# select a file in sharepoint from OneNote

Tags: sharepoint-online

My documents are managed in Sharepoint.
I want to link to a Sharepoint document from OneNote.
From OneNote where I work I need access to files in Sharepoint in an easy way for the user (browse and select).
Is this possible? If yes please tell me how.
I work in online mode, with the browser.
Regards,
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is supported at this time. The Windows 10 client version of OneNote just added "cloud attachments", but that feature only supports onedrive and not sharepoint, and again, that's not in the online version of OneNote.

And even copying links from SharePoint isn't straightforward. Depending on your configuration, the default "copy link" functionality in SharePoint may generate a link that grants permissions to the file to whomever has the link. Also, there doesn't seem to be a keyboard shortcut for getting a link in SharePoint either. So, it's switch to SharePoint, r-click the file, copy link, switch to OneNote and paste.

There are a couple items in the OneNote Online uservoice about this, but none with too many votes that I could find, and none have responses from MS.